# Как разделить строку на два числа через пробел. не используя split или join?

Tags: python, python-3.x

`a, b = (int(input(), int(input())` не работает

Answer (score 2):

Ну вот так, например:

```
inp = input()
ind = inp.index(' ')
a, b = int(inp[:ind]), int(inp[ind+1:])
```

То есть ищем, где в строке пробел, вроде бы на `str.index` запрета не было. После чего делим строку на две - до пробела и после пробела.

Или вот другой метод, без использования строковых функций:

```
n = ['','']
i = 0
for x in input():
  if x == ' ':
    i = 1
    continue
  n[i] += x
a, b = int(n[0]), int(n[1])
```

Comment: @A_Vaclav Ну то есть без строковых функций )  Исправлю

Answer (score 1):

После input-а вы получаете строку, например
input:

```
239 566
```

Вы получаете в питоне строку

```
s = "239 566"
```

дальше нужно разделить строку на две, у которых разделитель - проблел
Для этого я не вижу альтернатив кроме split - который вернет список строк
то есть

```
s = s.split()

#########
['239', '566']
#########
```

А дальше конверитьровать каждый элемент из строки в число
Тут уже разные варианты, самый простой и элегантный - с помощью функции map(a, b) - где a - действие над всеми элементами b
то есть в нашем случае нужно сделать так

```
a, b = map(int, s)
```

Полный пример:

```
s = input()
s = s.split()
a, b = map(int, s)
```

Если для вас пока сложны в понимании описаные выше функции - попробуйте считывать через enter

```
a = int(input())

# дальше в окное ввода нажмите `enter`

b = int(input())
```

Comment: Всё конечно так, но в вопросе сказано что слово split использовать нельзя.

Comment: Показалось что автор просто не понимает что это и для чего

Answer (score 1):

А регулярные выражения можно? *(Из пушки по воробьям :)*

```
import re

a,b = map(int, re.findall(r"-?\d+", input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Предложу ещё один метод:

```
a = input()
b,c = a[:a.find(' ')], a[a.find(' ')+1:]
```

Comment: Ну так себе дважды искать одно и то же. А с переменной ответ уже дали.